# How to remove space from an empty header

Tags: html, css, wordpress, widget

In the homepage of dollarcryptos.com (screenshot provided), I can't remove the empty header with two gray horizontal lines.

I've right clicked the source and if I am correct I believe this is the HTML code:

```html
<h4 class="td-block-title"><span></span></h4>
```

I am not sure if that is correct though.

What I want to do is delete those horizontal lines and move up the price boxes so it fits in nicely.

Info on what's used:

- I'm using Wordpress
- the empty header with horizontal lines along with the price display is a widget.

[image: home page]
<sub>(source: [dollarcryptos.com](https://dollarcryptos.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/homepage-1024x701.png))</sub>

I've tried:

```css
.sidebar.sidebar-right {
  border: none;
}
.widget {
  border: none;
}
```

in the additional CSS section of the *customize* option on Wordpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do

```
.home .ccpwp_Widget h4.td-block-title {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Yes! ALMOST! But it removed all the headers instead of just that one

Comment: `<h4 class="td-block-title"><span></span></h4> <!-- Cryptocurrency Widgets PRO 2.3.1  !-->` thats the header of the block..

Comment: It removed all the headers instead of just that specific one

Comment: I see, i didn't know there were others. i've changed the code in my answer to include only that one.